# provide feedback in nopcommerce

Tags: .net, asp.net, nopcommerce

I'm using nopcommerce as my shop and I have managed to get it working like a dream, but now I'm getting cocky and need the help of people wiser than me.

I want to give a 100% discount to any customer that can correctly guess my middle names. I want to provide feedback to any customer that gets any of the letters correct so that they can have a more educated guess on their next order.

I have no clue as to where to start on getting this idiot project started, so please be kind and give me a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is limit the game to either a limited number of registered users, or else write code to restrict the number of attempts by a particular IP.

Depending on the length of your middle names, I would give them a set number of attempts, at x number of letters at a time :-)

Comment: Currently only registered users can checkout and I am envisioning only one attempt before the cash transaction.I don't think my middle names will be easily guessed if the feed back is like hangman _a _z f__, etcetera.
I do want people to get the correct names and get their dicount, but not too quickly. ;)